# Jquery textbox value is empty

Tags: jquery

***If***

```
alert($(TheButton).parent().parent().children("td").html());
```

***returns***

```
<input id="Quantity" name="Quantity" 
style="width: 35px;
background-color: rgb(254, 254, 254);" type="text" value="1">
```

***why does***

```
alert($(TheButton).parent().parent().children("td").val());
```

***return an empty string?***

Comment: The `.parent().parent().children("td")` seems too hardcoded.. if you post your html, i am sure we can improve this selection..

Comment: Thanks for the offer! Very kind of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `td` elements don't have values.

When you call `.children('td')` what you are getting is a list of `td` elements.  When you call `.html()` what you are getting is the HTML *inside* the element.  In this case that HTML happens to be an `input` element.  But `.html()` doesn't discern that, it just returns what's there.

So in this case when you're calling `.children('td').val()` you're calling `.val()` on `td` elements, which have no values.  Maybe you meant to select the `input` element instead?

```
alert($(TheButton).parent().parent().children("td").find("input").val());
```

Comment: you are correct and thanks! - that alert pulled the context over the sheep's eyes.